# JOIN misses rows of duplicate data. Subquery works fine

Tags: mysql, sql

I give a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 ( id INT, flags INT ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE tb2 ( id INT ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES ( 2, 100 ), ( 2, 0 ), ( 3, 100 ), ( 1, 100 ), ( 3, 100 ), ( 4, 100 );
INSERT INTO tb2 VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 2 );
```

I want to select all ids, whose flags contain the number 100 only once.

When I use a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tb2 WHERE
id IN (SELECT id FROM tb1 WHERE flags=100 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) = 1);
```

I get the correct result:

```
1
2
```

When I use JOIN:

```
SELECT tb1.id FROM tb2 INNER JOIN tb1 ON tb1.id = tb2.id WHERE
tb1.flags=100 GROUP BY tb1.id HAVING COUNT(tb1.id) = 1;
```

I get wrong result:

```
1
```

Why? Thank You!

Comment: When you create tables, define your PRIMARY KEYs in each case, otherwise we get confused.

Comment: This is because of `GROUP BY tb1.id HAVING COUNT(tb1.id) = 1`. When you are joining, the whole result if affected by the `GROUP BY` clause. Try this query removing the group by, you'll get a result you can understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your question is why the 2nd query does not work.
Consider the query before the grouping:

```
SELECT 
  tb2.id tb2id, tb1.id tb1id, tb1.flags
FROM tb2 INNER JOIN tb1 
ON tb1.id = tb2.id 
WHERE tb1.flags=100 
ORDER BY tb2.id
```

The result is:

```
| tb2id | tb1id | flags |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
| 1     | 1     | 100   |
| 2     | 2     | 100   |
| 2     | 2     | 100   |
| 3     | 3     | 100   |
| 3     | 3     | 100   |
```

You can see that there are 2 rows with `tb1.id = 2` because the table `tb2` contains 2 rows with `id = 2`.
So the condition you apply when you group in the HAVING clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(tb1.id) = 1
```

rejects that `tb1.id = 2`.
So the 2 queries you have are different.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you want the second table to behave as if the `id` cannot appear in duplicate.  One way to do this would be to join to a subquery which removes the duplicate `id` values in the second table:

```
SELECT tb1.id
FROM tb1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tb2) tb2
    ON tb1.id = tb2.id
WHERE tb1.flags = 100
GROUP BY
    tb1.id
HAVING COUNT(tb1.id) = 1;
```

### Demo